# Why is airflow not a data streaming solution?

Tags: airflow

Learning about Airflow and want to understand why it is not a data streaming solution.

> https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/#beyond-the-horizon
>
> Airflow is not a data streaming solution. Tasks do not move data from
> one to the other (though tasks can exchange metadata!)

Not sure what the it means task do not move data from one to another. So I can't have tasks like Extract Data >> Calculate A >> Calculate B using data from prev step >> another step that depends on prev task's result >> ... ?

Furthermore read the following a few times and still doesn't click with me. What's an example of a static vs dynamic workflow?

> Workflows are expected to be mostly static or slowly changing. You can think of the structure of the tasks in your workflow as slightly more dynamic than a database structure would be. Airflow workflows are expected to look similar from a run to the next, this allows for clarity around unit of work and continuity.

Can someone help provide an alternative explanation or example that can walk through why Airflow is not a good data streaming solution?

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure what the it means task do not move data from one to another. So I can't have tasks like Extract Data >> Calculate A >> Calculate B using data from prev step >> another step that depends on prev task's result >> ... ?

You can use [XCom (cross-communication)](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#xcoms) to use data from previous step BUT bear in mind that XCom is stored in the metadata DB meaning that you should not use XCom for holding data that is being processed. You should use XCom for holding a reference to data (e.g.: S3/HDFS/GCS path, BigQuery table, etc).

So instead of passing data between tasks, in Airflow you pass reference to data between tasks using XCom. Airflow is an orchestrator, heavy tasks should be off-loaded to other data processing cluster (can be Spark cluster, BigQuery, etc).

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with streaming data you have a **constant flux** of information. Your tasks need to be constantly receiving, processing and outputting data from/to other tasks with **no end** in sight.

Airflow is not designed to deal with that. It is a tool suited to work with **batches** of data ideally representing an interval of time (like a day/week/month's worth). Meaning that at some point you finish processing your current batch and the task **ends**.

The workflow you described is perfectly possible in Airflow, but it would require your tasks to [communicate](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#communication), storing and reading intermediate values.